# Filter cartesian products (cartesian powers) in python based on majority constraint

Tags: python, combinatorics, cartesian-product

I would like to know the number of elements in the cardinal power X^n (cardinal product of one set X by itself, n times) with a majority constraint: how many elements in X^n have a (relative) majority of one element of the set (say x)?

On top of that, I'd like to fix one element in the cardinal power to a certain value (say the second), and count the number of possibilities with this fixed value.

Let's take a simple example, with X={A, B, C} and n=4. The question is: how many four-letter words with an A in the second position have a (relative) majority of A's (answer: 13, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146412/number-of-elements-in-cartesian-power-with-a-majority-constraint))? And how many have a (relative) majority of B's?

In a network with 3 rows ({A, B, C}) and n=4 columns, assuming paths from left to right (e.g., using node A1, then B2, then A3 and finally C3), the question becomes: how many paths are going through node A2 and have a (relative) majority of A nodes?

[I'm looking for a closed form formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146412/number-of-elements-in-cartesian-power-with-a-majority-constraint), but cannot find one.

Would it be possible to enumerate all products and filter them in python?

I have 8 elements in my original set, and I repeat them n=24 times. It's very large (>10'9), but it might be simplified, maybe?

Comment: You mean `itertools.product([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],repeat=24)` and filter? That is going to take a while

Comment: Yes, a while... I'm looking for some idea, maybe related to the symmetry of the problem, or anything, to express the problem in a different way and avoid enumerating.

Comment: I think I found a closed form formula: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146412/number-of-elements-in-cartesian-power-with-a-majority-constraint/1146564#1146564

Comment: The correct closed form formula is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146412/number-of-elements-in-cartesian-power-with-a-majority-constraint/1149759#1149759

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to filter and there is a closed form formula (see the mathematics [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146412/number-of-elements-in-cartesian-power-with-a-majority-constraint/1149759#1149759)).

Here is how to solve this problem in python (inspired from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/790876/94313)):

1. **Install [sympy](http://www.sympy.org)** in order to have **symbolic algebra** in python ([download](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/releases), decompress, go to the folder, `python setup.py install`, and that's it)
2. Import stuff

> from sympy.abc import x
>
> from sympy import expand
>
> from sympy import factorial

Careful: don't use factorial from math, but factorial from sympy; so don't `from math import factorial` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28583981/762435)).

3. **Expand** the **polynomial expression**

> d1 = expand()

4. **Extract** the **coefficient**

> print d1[x**n]

---

**For the simple example** [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146412/number-of-elements-in-cartesian-power-with-a-majority-constraint) (n=4, m=3), we need to import summation on top of that, the letters j, k,

> from sympy import summation
>
> from sympy.abc import j, k
>
> import math
>
> d1 = expand(summation(x**(k-1)/factorial(k-1)*summation(x**(j-1)/factorial(j-1), (j, 1, k))**2, (k, 0, 4))).as_coefficients_dict()
>
> d1[x**3] * math.factorial(3)

Solution is 13.

---

**For the large example,** with n=24, m=8:

> d2 = expand(summation(x**(k-1)/factorial(k-1)*summation(x**(j-1)/factorial(j-1), (j, 1, k))**7, (k, 0, 24))).as_coefficients_dict()
>
> d2[x**23] * math.factorial(23)

Solution is 105097074808684277656. Took 1-2 hour to compute.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot give you a theoretical answer, but here's some python code to get you started.

```
import itertools, collections

items = 'ABCDEFGH'
n = 4

r = collections.Counter()

# for symmetry reasons, it doesn't matter which position you "fix"
# so to count `'ABCD'^n` with fixed 'A' 
# we have to count `'ABCD'^n-1` and just add 1 for 'A'.    

for p in itertools.product(items, repeat=n-1):
    c = collections.Counter(p)
    c['A'] += 1
    m = c.most_common(2)
    if len(m) == 1 or m[0][1] > m[1][1]:
        r[m[0][0]] += 1
    else:
        r['no_major'] += 1

print r
```

Regarding your specific figures, iterating `8^24` items doesn't sound realistic. You have to derive a formula before you get this far!

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think I found a closed form formula: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146412/number-of-elements-in-cartesian-power-with-a-majority-constraint/1146564#1146564