# Summing factorials in Python

Tags: python, sum, sympy, factorial

I would like to compute sums with factorials using symbolic algebra in python. The simplest version of the problem I can generate is the following one:

```
from sympy.abc import j
from math import factorial
from sympy import summation
summation(factorial(j), (j, 1, 4))
```

And I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "sympy/core/expr.py", line 194, in __int__
    r = self.round(2)
  File "sympy/core/expr.py", line 3042, in round
    raise TypeError('%s is not a number' % type(x))
TypeError: <class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'> is not a number
```

Fundamentally, what I would like to compute is

```
summation(x**(j-1)/factorial(j-1), (j, 1, 3))
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Umm what is summation here..?

Comment: Sorry! I edited the question and added 'from sympy import summation'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Sympy's own `factorial` function (instead of the `math` module's factorial function) could perhaps return what you want.

Following your initial setup but omitting `from math import factorial`, you could then write:

```
>>> from sympy import factorial, symbols
>>> x = symbols('x')
>>> summation(x**(j-1)/factorial(j-1), (j, 1, 3))
x**2/2 + x + 1
```

This reduces the summation of the factorial series to a simple quadratic equation.

I notice you are calculating the sum of the first few terms of the power series expansion of `exp(x)`:

```
1 + x + x**2/2! + x**3/3! + ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of avoiding loops is a functional version :S:

```
from math import factorial

reduce(int.__add__,map(factorial,xrange(1,5)))
```